# Laravel 5.6 Auto-logout on Session Timeout

Tags: laravel, session, timeout, laravel-5.6

I'm very new to laravel framework. I am working on an app that when the user is inactive for 5 minutes, it's automatically log out. I have use code from here: https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-sessiontimeout/blob/master/src/Middleware/SessionTimeout.php but it doesn't seem to  work  for me.

This is the middleware code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Session\Store;

class SessionTimeOutMiddleware
{
  /**
  * Instance of Session Store
  * @var session
  */
  protected $session;
  /**
   * Time for user to remain active, set to 300 secs( 5 minutes )
   * @var timeout
  */
  protected $timeout = 300;
  public function __construct(Store $session){
   $this->session        = $session;
   $this->redirectUrl    = 'auth/login';
   $this->sessionLabel   = 'warning';
 }
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
  */
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
   if(! $this->session->has('lastActivityTime'))
   {
     $this->session->put('lastActivityTime', time());
   }
   else if( time() - $this->session->get('lastActivityTime') > $this->getTimeOut())
   {
     $this->session->forget('lastActivityTime');
     Auth::logout();
     return redirect($this->getRedirectUrl())->with([ $this->getSessionLabel() => 'You have been inactive for '. $this->timeout/60 .' minutes ago.']);
   }
   $this->session->put('lastActivityTime',time());
   return $next($request);
 }
 /**
 * Get timeout from laravel default's session lifetime, if it's not set/empty, set timeout to 15 minutes
 * @return int
 */
 private function getTimeOut()
 {
   return  ($this->lifetime) ?: $this->timeout;
 } 
 /**
 * Get redirect url from env file
 * @return string
 */
 private function getRedirectUrl()
 {
   return  (env('SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECTURL')) ?: $this->redirectUrl;
 } 
 /**
   * Get Session label from env file
   * @return string
 */
 private function getSessionLabel()
 {
   return  (env('SESSION_LABEL')) ?: $this->sessionLabel;
 }
```

}

and this is the `config/session.php` file

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 5),

'expire_on_close' => true,
```

and in `Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\SessionTimeOutMiddleware::class,
];
```

Is there anything else I have missed?
I have done so many research and seems to can't find the answer to this question. I would really be thankful if someone help me solve this.

Comment: in config/auth.php have a variable for session logout check it

Answer (score 7):

Set your driver to database in .env

```
CACHE_DRIVER=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This times out on web but not on mobile, my users are still logged in on mobile after two weeks but the web works fine